# Having trouble doing conditional validation

Tags: jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

While using the jQuery Validation plugin I'm trying to do a conditional validation on a text box. The rules for the text box are these: 1) required and needs to be within a range of 1-90 if the first radio button is marked. 2) if the second radio button is checked, the text box does not need to be considered.

So I've got the following code written for handing the required on the check of the first radio button:

```
$("#Form").validate({
    rules: {
      daysInputBox: {
         required: {
         depends: function () {
            return $('input:radio[name=days]:checked');
         },
         messages: {
            required: 'This field is required.'
         }
       }
     }
   }
});
```

Yet, when the code moves on to calling if the form is valid, I always get a true value back. Is there some black magic I'm missing here in making this validation work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making sure your depends function returns boolean value:

```
...
depends: function () {
  return $('input:radio[name=days]:checked').length !== 0;
},
...
```